# Pipenv refer to same package with different source?

Tags: pipenv

I have a project which consists of a CLI and an api. Since the cli has different users than the API, both exist as separate git repositories.
Frequently, developing on the CLI requires to edit the API on the same time. SO I would like to ease the dev workflow as much as possible, while keeping the cli as simple to use as possible.
Ideally, I would like to do this:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
api= {editable = true,path = "./../api"}

[packages]
api= {git = "<some git>s.git", ref = "master", editable = true}

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Unfortunately, the lxpy version in packages always seems to "win" - is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322260/give-pipenv-different-sources-or-git-urls-for-production-and-development